# What did Dudley hear when attacked by the Dementors?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

I've been re-reading the Harry Potter books over the last month, and this particular question occurred to me when reading the start of *Order of the Phoenix*. The following quote sums it up rather nicely:

> Dudley seemed incapable of saying. He shuddered again and shook his large blond head, and despite the sense of numb dread that had settled on Harry since the arrival of the first owl, he felt a certain curiosity. Dementors caused a person to relive the worst moments of their life. What would spoiled, pampered, bullying Dudley have been forced to hear?
>
> <sub>Chapter Two - A Peck of Owls, *Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

All I managed to find at the time was [this quote](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm) from JKR:

> Amy: What did Dudley see when he faced the Dementors in book five?
>
> JK Rowling replies -> Ah, good question. You'll find out!

So, thinking that perhaps there was something in one of the final two books that answered the question, I carried on reading. However, I'm now about a third of the way through the last book and this hasn't been answered; I don't recall there being any scenes with the Dursleys (other than a young Petunia) in the remainder of *Deathly Hallows* so I'm expecting to finish reading without an answer.

Is there any canon information (JKR writings, interviews or a book quote that I've missed or yet to read) that states what Dudley heard when he and Harry were attacked by the Dementors?

Comment: There's no book quote - the only other conversation it might have come out would have been in book 7 before the Dursleys left Privet Drive (when Dudley acted like Harry was a real person for the first time), and there was nothing there about what Dudley saw or heard.

Comment: @AdamV Yes, I didn't have much hope that there was one; all Dudley really says in book seven is "Thanks for saving my life." It's a bit annoying that JKR raised the question herself in the book, said in an interview that we'd find out, then seemingly never addressed it.

Comment: Totally agree! Now that I see the question, I want to know as well. Hopefully someone finds an interview where she answers it! It's quite possible she intended to have it in the book (just as she had intended for 'scar' to be the last word in the series), and it got cut for one reason or another.

Comment: There's a circular link between the two questions: this one and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55584/why-did-dumbledore-say-that-dudley-had-been-mistreated-by-the-dursleys?noredirect=1&lq=1. What are the chances of that!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to what he heard, but here it goes anyway:
As far as I remember it's never mentioned again in the books. I did find [this](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_did_dudley_see_with_the_dementors_in_the_Order_of_the_Pheonix), but not sure how credible it is

And here's the quote:

> "People usually ask me, what is it that Dudley saw during the
> Dementor attack?" Rowling said. "My feeling is that he saw himself,
> exactly for what he was, and for a boy that spoiled, it would be
> terrifying. So he was jolted out of it. Dementor attacks aren't
> usually good for people, but this one was."
>
> [Source](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1572399/harry-potter-author-jk-rowling-outs-dumbledore.jhtml)

Comment: Odd, now that you've posted it I feel like I've read that quote before.

Comment: I was also sure I had seen this question before as well, here on stackexchange, but couldn't find it

Comment: @user13267, it's here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55584/why-did-dumbledore-say-that-dudley-had-been-mistreated-by-the-dursleys

Comment: The transcript of the 2007 question and answer session that this article refers to http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html contains a similar quote: "I think that when Dudley was attacked by the Dementors he saw himself, for the first time, as he really was. This was an extremely painful, but ultimately salutory lesson, and began the transformation in him."

Answer (score -2):

I think he saw the times such as when Hagrid gave him a pig's tail (and the surgery he had to go through to get it removed), as well as the time Harry blew up his aunt or when his tongue grew 4 feet long. I think he would be scared of something like magic because it is the one thing he can't control.

Comment: While this certainly seems plausible, the accepted answer says something different. Is there any evidence (in the books or elsewhere) that this is what he saw?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Some of these suggestions seem more plausible than others to me, but it's not too important. What is important is to try and provide supporting evidence rather than reckons -- even more so to very old questions with multiply-upvoted accepted answers. Please don't be discouraged, you're absolutely not the first to run afoul of stackexchange, but we aren't a forum or chat room here and we tend to ask for and expect quite high standards, rather than people's two cents

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this, or is it just speculation?