# Did any Muggles actively fight against Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, muggles

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195084/why-didnt-dumbledore-or-mom-ask-for-muggle-help-to-search-for-the-chamber-of-se) question got me thinking

Did any Muggle (full blown "pure blood" Muggle with no magic; not Squib nor any wizard with majority Muggle relatives) actively fight against Voldemort?

Many of the witches and wizards that fought in the BoH (Battle of Hogwarts) were the husbands, wives, relatives or children of Muggles.

These Muggles were not completely oblivious of the wizard world unlike general Muggles. They would definitely be worried if their loved ones were targeted by or involved in any way with Voldemort, and possibly try anything in their power to help them.

Has there been any instance of a Muggle actively fighting against Voldemort? By this I don't mean giving passive help (for eg, Tonks' father, who was a Muggle, allowing Harry to stay in his house until he could be moved to the Burrow in DH), but actively fighting Voldemort, DE, going around raising awareness about Voldemort, etc? Has that ever happened in canon (books PS to DH) or the extended universe (Pottermore, interviews, twitter, movies, etc)? Since the answer will possibly be short, we can include both WW (Wizard War) I and II.

(If there are any instances of a Muggle actively fighting *for* Voldemort, that can be included too. I am just assuming nothing like that could ever happen, as Voldemort would probably never recruit a Muggle.)

Comment: Now I really want a story about one-- a Muggle who has only a vague idea of what's going on, but knows that someone very dangerous is trying to cause a lot of trouble for a lot of people. So now they're trying to do whatever they can to help the cause: write letters to send by owl, get their friends and relatives out of harm's way, etc.

Comment: @Pluto Canon example of such a muggle would probably be the muggle Prime Minister (*has only a vague idea of what's going on, but knows that someone very dangerous is trying to cause a lot of trouble for a lot of people*), and he didn't do anything at all

Comment: @user13267 Muggle PM actually sent a Special Ops team to fight against Death Eaters in BoH. But, soon, they forgot which side they were on.

Comment: Tonks's father was a muggle-born, not a muggle: *“Andromeda’s sisters are still here because they made lovely, respectable pure-blood marriages, but Andromeda married **a Muggle-born, Ted Tonks**, so —”*

Comment: @Alex then who was it that had a muggle husband? Or did that never happen in the books? (*feel another question cooking up*)

Comment: @user13267 A bunch of people. Seamus Finnigan's mother, Snape's mother, Merope Gaunt, etc.

Comment: We have to consider that Voldemort never really came out in the open, nor was there any pitched battle/major skirmish of any sort even within the wizarding community. The whole secrecy was still maintained, the school still run, the ministry still worked normally. Note that even the Weasleys(famously blood-traitors) were not targeted as long as Ron was not known to be travelling with Harry. So my guess is nobody but the muggle PM & some select few knew about the whole mess. They may have taken some steps, but not actively fought.

Comment: parents of muggle-born wizards i'm sure had some part in the fight.

Answer (score 12):

## No Muggles fighting the Dark Lord have ever been mentioned.

There’s no mention of any Muggles taking part in the fight either against or for the Dark Lord. While it is theoretically possible, no instances of it were shown to the reader. Frank Bryce confronted him before being killed, but he wasn’t actively fighting to stop the Dark Lord from gaining power.

> “I am calling you a Muggle,’ said the voice coolly. ‘It means that you are not a wizard.’
>
> ‘I don’t know what you mean by wizard,’ said Frank, his voice growing steadier. ‘All I know is I’ve heard enough to interest the police tonight, I have. You’ve done murder and you’re planning more! And I’ll tell you this, too,’ he added, on a sudden inspiration, ‘my wife knows I’m up here, and if I don’t come back –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

Of course, he wasn’t actively participating in the fight against the Dark Lord. He didn’t know (though he realized at least after he was killed) that the Dark Lord was a wizard, and he had no idea exactly who the Dark Lord was in the larger picture. He is a Muggle shown facing the Dark Lord, though.

> “Is that right?’ said Frank roughly. ‘Lord, is it? Well, I don’t think much of your manners, *my Lord*. Turn round and face me like a man, why don’t you?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

He knows he’s in danger, but he doesn’t know exactly who he’s dealing with.

## The closest thing shown is Arabella Figg, a Squib, in the Order.

The closest thing shown to a Muggle actively working to stop the Dark Lord from gaining power is Arabella Figg, who’s a Squib, not actually a Muggle. She of course wouldn’t count as a Muggle fighting the Dark Lord because she’s not one. However, she still has no magic. Therefore, it’s also theoretically possible for a Muggle who’s aware of the wizarding world to help the same way she did (though no Muggles are actually shown doing anything similar).

> “I’m a Squib, as Mundungus knows full well, so how on earth was I supposed to help you fight off Dementors? He left you completely without cover when I’d warned him –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 2 (A Peck of Owls)*</sup></sub>

She isn’t shown doing anything against the Dark Lord specifically, but she does help rescue Harry from the Dementors, and helps get him acquitted when he’s on trial. What she does (at least what we know of it) would probably be classified as passive help. But she’s still the only member of the Order, an organization whose goal is to fight the Dark Lord, who can’t use magic.

Comment: Always felt that Frank deserved a posthumous honourary Wizarding bravery award for that scene.

Answer (score 9):

There is a name I want to mention. It is not the answer you are looking for and @bellatrix’s answer is much more complete but it just felt unjust not to mention her name.

**Petunia Dursley**

She lost a sister in the first Wizarding War and she accepted Harry as her family which protected him from Voldemort and Death Eaters until he was 17. This is truly a sacrifice for her because it led to harm of her own kid( Dementor Attack) and many weird events that made her husband angry as he is depicted as a person who literally hates weirdness since page 1. She could just reject him first day in her doorsteps.

You are looking for active fighters but not everyone is a fighter as we know. She took care of Harry, she fed him for 17 years and promised Dumbledore to keep him safe.  This is her role in the battle as a fighter and she is aware of most of the things and knows the danger.

Comment: #honorablemention

Comment: "She took care of Harry, she fed him for 17 year" - barely

Comment: The Dursleys did vastly more harm to Dudley than the Dementor attack did. In fact, the Dementor attack [seems to be one of the best things that happened to him](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39901/5833). Vernon's attitudes towards "weirdness" were strongly shared by Petunia and she was shown to have pretty strong anti-wizard feelings before she met him. They didn't "take care of" Harry, they let him live in their house, basically treating him like a slave.

Answer (score 0):

The number of Muggles who even know that there is a wizard going by the name of Voldemort must be a very small number.

The Muggle Prime Minister knows that wizards exist, and that one of them is trying to take over, but he hasn't been clued in on the details.

It is likely that some Muggle spouses of wizards have been told more, and I am sure they are doing all that they can do, but that isn't a whole lot.